# How to make automated notifcation Sender using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-deployment

I wanted to make a function which will send the list of users a notification (Email) and want this to continue after every 6 hrs regularly.
Something like this

```
function(){
   if(currentTime==scheduledTime){
      //Triger notification sender
      sendNotification();
      scheduledTime = (scheduledTime + 6 hrs);
   }
}
```

How can I implement this Feature. Also, where can I deploy this website with this kind of functionality for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use node-cron instead.You can setup the interval using cron syntax and it will run in a scheduled manner.

```
npm install --save node-cron
```

Then :

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* */6 * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every 6 hours');
  sendNotification();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! for helping. I'll use cron package. But can you tell me where can I host my website so that it will send the list of users emails after I deploy this. I was earlier thinking of heroku but as far as I know heroku dynaos gets off after some time and get on when it is accessed nest time. We have to pay to keep it running everytime. Is there any other option where I can deploy it for free.

Comment: you can use aws ec2, you get to run you code for around 750hrs/month for free.